# Using recursion method and returning a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given a list `L1`, position `P`, element `A`. I am trying to return a new list in which the element `A` is added at position `P` in the List `L1` and return the answer in this way:

> ```
> ?- add_member(1,3,[2,3,4,5],A).
>
> X=[2,3,1,4,5].
> ```

**This is my code:**

```
 add_member(X, P, [H|T], NewList) :-
  (P>1, 
    write('p>1 start | '),
    P1 is P-1, 
    add_member(X, P1, T, Newlist1), 
    NewList is [H, Newlist1]), 
    write('p>1 end ');
  (P=1, 
    write('p=1 start | '), 
    NewList is [X,H|T], 
    write('p=1 end | ')).
```

Here `P` is the position, `X` is the element to be inserted. I have used `write('---')` to know how the code works(like debug). **This is its output(with error):**

```
?- add_member(1,3,[2,3,4,5],x).
p>1 start | p>1 start | p=1 start | 
ERROR: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[1,4,5]' (a list) ("x" must hold one character)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [13] _22972 is [1,4|...]
ERROR:   [12] add_member(1,1,[4,5],_23016) at /mnt/c/Users/mill/Documents/q2.pl:1
ERROR:   [11] add_member(1,2,[3,4|...],_23058) at /mnt/c/Users/mill/Documents/q2.pl:5
ERROR:   [10] add_member(1,3,[2,3|...],x) at /mnt/c/Users/mill/Documents/q2.pl:5
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/toplevel.pl:1117
```

Here, `q2.pl` is the name of the file and `toplevel.pl` is not accessible. I am using windows subsystem for linux (wsl).

How can I complete the code? Is there a concept that I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is/2`is a buildin predicate that requires that the second argument is a term that is arithmetically resolvable (examples: `3+6`, `7*3`).

In your example, you use `NewList is [H, Newlist1]` where the second argument is a list and not an arithmetic expression. Therefore you get a type error. You should use the matching operator `=` instead.

The second problem with your code is that `[H, Newlist1]` builds up a nested list (it is a list of length 2, the first element is `H` and the second is the list `Newlist1`. Here is the corrected version of your code:

```
add_member(X, P, [H|T], NewList) :-
  (P>1,
    write('p>1 start | '),
    P1 is P-1,
    add_member(X, P1, T, Newlist1),
    NewList = [H|Newlist1],
    write('p>1 end '))
  ;
  (P=1,
    write('p=1 start | '),
    NewList = [X,H|T],
    write('p=1 end | ')).
```

Two more remarks:

- the insertion of an element at the first position of an empty list should be captured as well.
- using disjunction (`;`) within a Prolog clause with more than a trivial alternatives code is not recommended (at least it should be used with care). Thus it is better to split your clause in two clauses (one for `P=1` and one for `P>1`):

  ```
   add_member(X, 1, List, [X|List]).
   add_member(X, P, [H|T], [H|NewList]) :-
       P>1,
       P1 is P-1,
       add_member(X, P1, T, NewList).
  ```